# How to update looping data into core data?

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview

I have tableView, and I already succeed saved it into core data (create new in core data).

When I update, it only update base on last data, not all data, and it cause the other data filled with the last data. so the result like this:
[image]

the actual is the first and the second tableView cell data different, but after update, it copy last data to other data.

This is my update code :

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                        return
                    }
                    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
                    let fetchRequestPhone = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Phone")
                    do {
                        let phones = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequestPhone)
                        if (phones.count > 0) {
                            for phone in phones {
                                phone.setValue(phoneNameValue, forKey: "phoneName")
                                phone.setValue(phoneNumberValue, forKey: "phoneNumber")
                                do{
                                    try managedContext.save()
                                } catch let error as NSError {
                                    print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    }
```

What is the correct code to repair this?

Comment: because I do not know which one should updated, so I fetching all and update all

Comment: user able to change name (the first textfield) and number (the second textfield), each of it have unique id

Comment: @Kamran, it is fetch to get all of the list, not update

Comment: In this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751632/update-core-data-object-swift-3, it is only update one record